# Can I change the search order for the physical views of an ASP.Net MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I noticed Asp.net MVC 3 searches for .aspx files before .cshtml files. Can I change this search order? And how to do this?

#### Background information

When debugging I got the following exception:

```
The view 'Reset' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Demo/Reset.aspx
~/Views/Demo/Reset.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Reset.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Reset.ascx
~/Views/Demo/Reset.cshtml
~/Views/Demo/Reset.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Reset.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Reset.vbhtml
```

I conclude from this, that the old .aspx views are searched for first.

Since I converted my site to MVC3, and all views to Razor, I would like the .cshtml files to be searched first. I think this would be better for performance.

Comment: +1 Good point caring for high performance... but this is cached, so it will perform well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [Change the order of the existing view engines.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/11/14/mvc-areas-and-multiple-view-engines.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0).

But in a non-debug configuration, file locations are cached, so it will only help on the first lookup. I wouldn't sweat it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [the answer of Craig Stuntz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198566/can-i-change-the-search-order-for-the-physical-views-of-an-asp-net-mvc-3-applicat/4198617#4198617) I found the syntax I was looking for:

I added this to my `Application_Start` in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine()); 
    // ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine()); <-- uncomment if needed
```

This clears the registered ViewEngines, and adds them in the order I want.

Comment: If you're not using Aspx at all you need not add `WebFormViewEngine`. However, as Craig mentioned, it shouldn't matter for an application running on the server.